# Relocate user to Registration page if login inputs are empty. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have got login page. There are two inputs - login and password. 
I need a Script like if user press **Login** button and my two inputs(login and password) are empty it will relocate user to registration page.
Its url is `http://localhost:8080/app/login` and i need to redirect to this URL `http://localhost:8080/app/registration`. 
**This is my Login page**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Войти в систему | Haine and Vold</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<c:url value="/resources/faviicon/iconHV.ico"/>" type="image/x-icon">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/CSS/styles.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Angular/angular.min.js"/>"></script>

</head>
<body>


<span class="text-center">
        <span class="rusLogo"><a href="?locale=ru"><img
                src="<c:url value="/resources/languageicons/rus.png"/>"
                alt="Russian Language" title="Сменить язык интерфейса на русский"></a>
                <a href="?locale=en"><img
        src="<c:url value="/resources/languageicons/usa.png"/>"
                alt="USA Language" title="Change interface language to american"></a>
                </span>

</span>
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive logo" src="/app/resources/logo.jpg">
</div>
    <br>
    <div class="centerBlock text-center loginForm">
        <form:form method="post" action="j_spring_security_check"
            name="myForm" commandName="users" modelAttribute="users">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="alert alert-error">${message}</div>

                <form:input class="form-control input-sm" path="username"
                    id="username" type="text" name="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

                <form:input class="form-control input-sm" path="password"
                    type="password" name="password" id="password"/>


            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
                    <spring:message code="label.loginbutton" />
                </button>
            </div>

        </form:form>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"/>"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    if($('#username').val().trim().length == 0 && $('#password').val().trim().length == 0){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = '/app/registration'
    }
});
```